# Installation of applications in Debian OS

Tags: linux, debian, redhat, installation-package

As usual, every two weeks you get a new package with a new version of the application. which need to be installed on approximately 1,200 production servers.

What's your idea for the realization of this task? One can assume that your OS is Debian.?

what I did. I just created a simple script which inside contain the installation comand .

apt-get install chrome

But I dont know commands which can help me to  install the application to manny other servers (1200) which I have acces to it through remotely .  any suggestions..?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to make a cron job.

```
$ crontab -e
```

And add a new line:

```
0 0 * * 0 root (apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y) > /dev/null
```

This will run full a system update every Sunday midnight.

If you want to update only `chrome`:

```
0 0 * * 0 root (apt-get update && apt-get --only-upgrade install -y chrome) > /dev/null
```

Comment: Hii this will run full system update but will it install that update to all 1200 servers ..?? by the way thanks for your answer

Comment: You can add this cron job to every server, and each server will be updating automatically and independently from others.

Comment: Thanks bro I solved my issue through your help and mr @filipe

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following article. This can help you:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/hack-and-manage-multiple-servers-efficiently